# jquery to change the src value of an img tag

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, image, src

The jquery below changes the src value to whatever I specify, however this gets applied to all  tags.

```
$("img").attr({src: "/_layouts/images/Flags_Germany_resized.png"});
```

I have  tags which do have an id, for this reason I would like to know how to select an specific  tag by using its title rather than id.

The img tags for which I would like to change the src value are as follows:

```
<img title="Folder: Germany" alt="Folder: Germany" src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif" 
border="0" complete="complete"/>

<img title="Folder: Angola" alt="Folder: Angola" src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif" 
border="0" complete="complete"/>

<img title="Folder: Russia" alt="Folder:Russia" src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif" 
border="0" complete="complete"/>
```

Any suggestions or assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('img[title="Folder: Germany"]').attr({src: "/_layouts/images/Flags_Germany_resized.png"});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 3):

Like so

```
$('img[title="Folder: Germany"]')
```

Comment: That will error in later jQuery versions due to the space. Need to quote the attribute value.

Comment: @Utkanos he did quote it about 3 seconds after posting. `:P`

Comment: Ah yes it's just changed. Was unquoted when I posted that, though, else I clearly wouldn't have :)

Comment: This websockets thing lags me often as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look into attribute selectors. These work in jQuery (almost) like they do in CSS.

```
$('img[title="some title here"]').attr('src', 'some/new/src.jpg');
```